# is introsort better than merge sort (Time Complexity)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, introsort

Please explain why does C++ sort() algorithm uses introsort? and in which cases does it perform better than regular mergeSort algorithm

Comment: _"Please explain why does C++ sort() algorithm uses introsort?"_ Does it? What's your evidence. Elaborate please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ — introsort was invented by Alex Stepanov and implemented in his Standard Template Library, which was partially incorporated into the C++ standard library. While it’s not required, it’s the typical implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker interesting, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) states that David Musser was the creator of IntroSort.

Comment: You have to take Time Complexity with a grain of salt. Two competing algorithms with the same Time Complexity can have radically different actual runtimes given the same data. There are also many cases where O(1) algorithms are overshadowed by brute force counterparts that are predictable and cache friendly.

Comment: @Fureeish — whoops, you’re right. STL was a joint effort of Stepanov and Musser. By the time I got involved with it during C++ standardization it was just Stepanov. Too late to edit my incorrect comment.

Comment: Old but interesting paper: https://cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/writing/samples/bentley93engineering.pdf. Its traces can still be found in STL (Microsoft, at least).

Comment: In the case of Visual Studio, std::sort (hybrid insertion + intro sort) is only about 15% faster than std::stable_sort (hybrid insertion + merge sort, using 1/2 array size for working space, which slows it down a bit). Merge sort does more moves but fewer compares than intro sort. If compare overhead is greater than move overhead, such as sorting an array of pointers to objects, then merge sort is faster.

Comment: [Efficient Verified Implementation of Introsort and Pdqsort](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7324064/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is introsort better than merge sort (Time Complexity)?

Both algorithms have the same asymptotical time complexity: O(N log N) in both worst and average case.

> Please explain why does C++ sort() algorithm uses introsort?

Assuming you mean the standard algorithm `std::sort`, it is not guaranteed to be implemented using introsort. You may be referring to some specific implementation(s).

> and in which cases does it perform better than regular mergeSort algorithm

Usually in cases where the data has high cache locality and the length of the input range is small.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention space-complexity as well.

Comment: Since it's a combination of quicksort and heap sort, it's most probably done in place. In that case, O(n) space complexity.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax I didn't mean that, plus, it's incorrect. HeapSort is O(1) *additional* space, but QuickSort is typically O(logn), due to recursion depth (iterative variant with custom-implemented stack of indexes yields practically the same velue). So will be IntroSort. The main difference is that MargeSort always uses *additional* O(n) memory, which is a simple tradeoff, given the fact that MergeSort *guarantees stability*, while neither QuickSort, HeapSort nor IntroSort do.

Comment: @Fureeish For the record, merge sort can be done in `O(log n)` space. The price paid is an extra `log n` factor for time complexity.

Comment: @user58697 MergeSort can also be done in `O(1)` space, but it's inefficient, since the overhead of time complexity is simply not worth it. I had the most commonly used implementations in mind, but I have to admit that it's not that uncommon to encounter a MergeSort which operates in `O(logn)` space.

Comment: @Fureeish I wish I knew the `O(1)` implementation, which is still stable. Kronrod's is not, and its time complexity is dismal indeed. I was talking about STL's [stable_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, quicksort is preferable to merge sort. But quicksort behaves badly on data that’s nearly sorted to begin with; introsort fixes some of the perverse cases.